# Tree structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tree

i need to create a tree structure from array of Javascript objects.
I have something like this (not defined children level):

```
var obj_1 = {id:1, title:"Title 1", parent:0};
var obj_2 = {id:2, title:"Title 1.1", parent:1};
var obj_3 = {id:3, title:"Title 1.2", parent:1};
var obj_4 = {id:4, title:"Title 1.1.1", parent:2};
var obj_5 = {id:5, title:"Title 2", parent:0};

var obj_list = [obj_1,obj_2,obj_3,obj_4,obj_5];
```

And I need:

```
var result = [{
               id:1, 
               title:"Title 1", 
               children:[
                        {id:2, title:"Title 1.1", children:[....]}
                        {id:3, title:"Title 1.2"}
                        ]
               },
               {
                ...
               }
              ];
```

With this structure I want to create HTML list:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Title 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Title 1.1</a>
            <ul>
             <li>Title 1.1.1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Title 1.2</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><li><a>Title 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestion to solve this ?
The intermediate structure isn't very important but what I need is the HTML list.

Comment: This isn't difficult but you ask for very specific code. What's your problem when you try to write it ? Do you have a problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting your objects list into a nested object:

```
var obj_nested_list = [],
    obj;

function fill_with_children(children_arr, parent_id) {
    // find all objs with parent "parent"
    for (var i = 0; i < obj_list.length; i++) {
        obj = obj_list[i];
        if (obj.parent == parent_id) {
            children_arr.push(obj);
            obj.children = [];
            fill_with_children(obj.children, obj.id);
        }
    }

    children_arr.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.title.downcase == b.title.downcase;
    });
}

fill_with_children(obj_nested_list, 0);
```

Using the nested object to print nested lists:

```
function print_list(list, container) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = list[i].title;
        if (list[i].children.length > 0) {
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            li.appendChild(ul);
            print_list(list[i].children, ul);
        }
        container.appendChild(li);
    }
}
print_list(obj_nested_list, document.getElementById('list'));
```

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/rotev/svFTa/1/

Comment: What should I do to order children by title ?

Comment: Use the array.sort() function every time a children array is ready. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you need. I suggest learning about recursion, the makeUL function would be a good start.

```
var obj_1 = {id:1, title:"Title 1", parent:0};
var obj_2 = {id:2, title:"Title 1.1", parent:1};
var obj_3 = {id:3, title:"Title 1.2", parent:1};
var obj_4 = {id:4, title:"Title 1.1.1", parent:2};
var obj_5 = {id:5, title:"Title 2", parent:0};
// make an object keyed by the ID
var root = {};
var cnt = 1;
try { obj = eval("obj_" + cnt); } catch(err) { obj = null; }
while(obj) {
    obj.children = [];
    root[obj.id] = obj;
    try { obj = eval("obj_" + (++cnt)); } catch(err) { break; }
}
// make the object treeified list
var list = []
for(var k in root) {
    var node = root[k];
    if(node.parent != 0) {
        root[node.parent].children.push(node);
    } else {
        list.push(node);
    }
}
// make HTML UL
function makeUL(list, result) {
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        var node = list[i];
        var li = result.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
        var a = li.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
        a.innerHTML = node.title;
        if(node.children.length > 0) {
            makeUL(node.children, li.appendChild(document.createElement("ul")));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
var result = makeUL(list, document.createElement("ul")); 
console.log(result);
```